# Is there a way to publish an HTML website on a mac?

Tags: html, macos, web

I'm not doing it just asking if there is a way to publish an HTML website on a mac?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; [Superuser](https://superuser.com) and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) are better places to ask about things like this. But the short answer is: sure, it's not much different from any other unixish platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publishing websites works the same way on Mac as any other OS.
Just open a web hosting service (like 000wwebhost) from a browser and upload your files( HTML, CSS,JS, Python, etc.).